# Test ruby/rails facebook api

Tags: ruby, testing, facebook-graph-api, httpwebrequest, mocking

Are there any ruby gems that mock out the requests and responses against the Facebook Graph Api?  I would start using fakeweb but I feel as though this may have been done.